# How to use boost::asio properly? (TCP server)

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am currently trying to create a server program which responds to SSL encrypted TCP packets that come in from multiple clients.

I already tried myself to realize this with multithreaded sockets (no boost yet, I simply created a new thread for every new client) but since I'm rather unexperienced with threads (especially the resource sharing part) it doesn't work well.
The problems start when the program recieves packets from at least two different clients
at the approximate same time.

So I decided to search for some kind of API that would do the socket stuff for me (I mean why reinvent everything?) and I stumbled upon boost::asio.
It sounded promising since it had SSL support and was promised to be very efficient compared to all those threads.

However I have now some difficulties to understand how the whole thing is supposed to work. Or better said, I'm unsure how I can implement it in my already working code.

Here's how it currently works:

- the server listens on two different ports for any incoming packets so I made two threads where I check if any clients are connecting/sending stuff (if they are already connected and sending something then it happens in a subthread)
- I check for new clients with accept and return a socket so I know where to respond to
- then once a packet comes in, I read the header first with SSL_read(...) (because its SSL encrypted) to determine the packet size and then use SSL_read again to save the data in a buffer and return the data
- once that is done, I read the data and do something depending on whats in it and then create a new packet that I send pack to the client with SSL_write

However I also have some "personal things" of each connected client saved in the subthread where I check for incoming packets and I need to be able to access them whenever I send a packet back to the corresponding client (thats why the socket also needs to be the same throughout the conversation until the client disconnects).

And now I'm unsure how to realize this with boost::asio (or if it is even possible at all). I already went through some of the examples but couldn't get much out of it.

So I would very much appreciate it if someone could give me a short decscription of how the thing could be realized similar to what I did above, thanks in advance.

Comment: Personally, I used Asio for stream server and it has a success history in network software and a good support for ssl. Please explain more, after two readings the work, I can't understand what you want.

Comment: It seems that SSL server example answers to all your questions: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp

Comment: ok then I'll simply ask some concrete questions about the ssl example (I already compiled and debugged it to understand how it works). 
1: does the code in the example already support multiple clients that are connecting and if yes how can I differ between the clients (concrete code example)? 

2: from what I can tell, "io_service.run()" simply checks for incoming connections/packets, is that so? and if yes, what do I have to do once a client connects (in order to get the data)? because nothing happens when I try to connect...

3:how do I send it back? I'm not sure how to adress each client

Comment: Ok sry it seems there was a problem with the SSL settings so now I am able to establish a connection and read from the packets. I'll look more into it (still unsure how to handle mutliple clients) and if more problems occurs, I'll report back thanks for spending the time reading here though ;)